# Android Room Subquery

Tags: android, android-room

when trying subquery in room database I got syntax error in comma , in this part
***(Customer.deptCode,***

```
    @Query("SELECT Customer.* FROM Customer WHERE (Customer.deptCode,Customer.engCode,Customer.areaCode,Customer.dayCode," +
        "Customer.mainCode,Customer.faryCode) " +
        "= (SELECT Counter.deptCode,Counter.engCode,Counter.areaCode,Counter.dayCode,Counter.mainCode,Counter.faryCode FROM Counter " +
        "WHERE Counter.counterNo = :counterNo);")
Single<List<Customer>> findCustomersByCounterNo(String counterNo);
```

Comment: In the `Counter` subquery, you have a reference to the `Customer` table.

Comment: i have corrected it,same issue

Comment: @Query("SELECT Customer.* FROM Customer WHERE (Customer.deptCode,Customer.engCode,Customer.areaCode,Customer.dayCode," +
            "Customer.mainCode,Customer.faryCode) " +
            "= (SELECT Counter.deptCode,Counter.engCode,Counter.areaCode,Counter.dayCode,Counter.mainCode,Counter.faryCode FROM Counter " +
            "WHERE Counter.counterNo = :counterNo);")
    Single<List<Customer>> findCustomersByCounterNo(String counterNo);

Comment: Please edit your post instead. Does the error still happens?

Comment: yes ,same issue